# Why does a cartesian product yield "TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array"?

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I am trying to make a cartesian product from a list of arrays but it keeps giving me a `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`

I have a list which looks like:

```py
print(a)
>>>[array([1., 2.]), array([3., 4.]), array(1400.)]
```

Now, when I try to do:

```py
b=list(itertools.product(*a))
>>>TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @user2357112 in the comments, you currently have the last element as a 0 dimensional array. If you check the length of it, you will get `TypeError: len() of unsized object`. To get your solution working, you need to enclose the element in the last array using  `[]` to be able to use the `product`

```
import itertools

a = [np.array([1., 2.]), np.array([3., 4.]), np.array([1400.])]

b = list(itertools.product(*a))

#[(1.0, 3.0, 1400.0),
# (1.0, 4.0, 1400.0),
# (2.0, 3.0, 1400.0),
# (2.0, 4.0, 1400.0)]
```

**Edit** answering second question on request:

```
import itertools

dict1 = {'wdth_i': ['1', '2'], 'wdth_p': ['3', '4'], 'mu': '1400'}

a = [] 
for i in dict1.values():
    if isinstance(i, list):
        a.append(i)  
    else:
        a.append([i])

f = list(itertools.product(*a))
# [('1', '3', '1400'),
#  ('1', '4', '1400'),
#  ('2', '3', '1400'),
#  ('2', '4', '1400')]
```

Comment: The last array is not a tuple of length 0. It's a 0-dimensional array. It has one element and no length (which is different from having length 0), and it is not a tuple.

Comment: @user2357112: Ok, I edited my wordings. If you downvoted, kindly revert it or suggest further improvements to make the answer more clearer. Thanks for commenting

Comment: `product` isn't a module, and the `*` unpacking isn't the part where things go wrong, but the biggest issue was fixed.

Comment: Now I have another issue with the unpacking that happens at the product: I have a dict which is like  `dict1={{'wdth_i': ['1', '2'], 'wdth_p': ['3', '4'], 'mu': '1400'}`, so when I do,
'a=[]
a.append(i) for i in dict1.values()
f=list(itertools.product(*a))'
It "explodes" the value of mu i.e. '1400' into '1' '4' '0' '0' and the gives me a cartesian product as such:
 '[('1', '3', '1'), ('1', '3', '4'), ('1', '3', '0'), ('1', '3', '0'), ('2', '3', '1'), ('2', '3', '4'), ('2', '3', '0'), ('2', '3', '0')]'. 
What am I missing?